# Unable to recognize columns in CSV file except in Excel

Tags: excel, parsing, csv, escaping, heidisql

I have a following CSV file:

```
col1;col2;col3;col4
row11;row12;row13;row14
row21;row22;row23;row24
row31;row32;row33;row34
row41;row42;row43;row44
```

Now, this file can be opened nicely in Excel, which recognizes the columns and the rows separation, but any of the other software I tried (some specialized in CSV editing, and some for other purposes, like HeidiSQL which I used to import the CSV files into tables), so this poses an issue. Theres around 200 rows, with 30 or so solumns, so manually doing this is a really hard task.

Do you know a way to make this a "proper" CSV?

Thanks!

Comment: use a text editor (find, replace all) or a programming language to change the `;` to `,`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csv = comma separated variables - your file is using semi colons instead of commas, change to commas and it should work

Comment: Well, my mind was blocked, I didn't try that. I know I had some CSVs before with ";" as delimiter, and I have the option in Heidi to chose the character used for separation of fields, but for some reason it didn't worked here, and excel then later messed up the format as well.

This helped though, managed to import the file. Thanks!